# Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be defined by $S=\{(m+\frac{1}{4^{|p|}}, n+\frac{1}{4^{|q|}}):m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be defined by $S=\{(m+\frac{1}{4^{|p|}}, n+\frac{1}{4^{|q|}}):m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.
. Then,

1. S is discrete in $\mathbb R^2$ .
2. The set of limit points of S is the set {(m,n);m,n $\in \mathbb Z$}.

[i don't understand this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310462/let-s-subset-mathbbr2-be-defined-by-s-m-frac14p-n-frac1)

Comment: If A is the set of limit points of S, then S⊆A ?? in this link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discrete set:** Discrete set is a set of points of a topological space such that each point in the set is an isolated point, i.e. a point that has a neighborhood that contains no other points of the set.

Clearly, $(5/4,1)$ is a limit point of $S$ and $(5/4,1)\not\in \{(m,n);m,n ∈\mathbb Z\}$.
Also $(1,1)\in S$ and $(1,1)$ is limit point as $(1,1)=(0+1/4^0, 0+1/4^0)$.

Thus $S$ is not discrete set.
Hence both the two options are incorrect.